# Insert negative value into SQL Server decimal column throws error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am having problem with negative decimal.

In a SQL Server database I have defined `price` as `decimal(8,2) NULL`

and the code I am using in C#:

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO ticket_elements " +
                             "(ticket_id, product_name, price, tax, amount) " +
                             VALUES ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
                                 ticket_id, pro2.ProductName, tPrice, tax, fixedAmountStr);
```

When `{2}` also the price not negative value is, then its working fine but when I set the price like `-0.25` then its giving this error:

> Arithmetic Overflow on converting varchar in numeric-datatype.

What do I need to do to use negative values in db?

Update:

but the following code just working fine with negative or positive values.

I am really confused.

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO tickets " +
                             "(registration_date, cancellation, cancellation_date,    total_products, total_gross_price, total_net_price, pay_type, user_id, client_id)" +
                             " VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}',  '{5}', '{6}', {7}, {8});" +
                             " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", regData, "False", "", this.TotalProducts, totalGrossPrice, totalNetPrice, this.PayType, this.CashierId,  this.ClientId);
```

Comment: You're passing EVERYTHING in as a string for each parameter. Bad idea. Better to either use a parameterized query (as Testujin pointed out) or make sure any non-string values are passed in as literals (SQL will infer the type based on columns). In other words, get rid of the apostraphes around your price, tax, and amount column parameters (so `{2}, {3}, {4}` instead of `'{2}','{3}','{4}'`)

Comment: still works only with positive numbers. Btw. how the 2. code part works and the 1. one not.. i am really tired of it

Comment: Then I'm assuming one of your columns (price, tax, amount) has no decimal specified. Check to make sure none of them were created as DECIMAL(#,0) or NUMERIC(#,0). Either way, those columns should be MONEY data type.

Comment: THANK YOU ! NOW ITS WORK. The problem was tax was decimal (3,2) I just made it decimal(8,2). I ll complatelly change all inserts to parameterized code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameterized queries instead. It saves you from injection attacks, and is actually faster han passing in straight SQL with hardcoded values (because the server can cache the compiled parameterized query and only sends the values). This is how you'd do it:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO ticket_elements " +
"(ticket_id, product_name, price, tax, amount) " +
"VALUES (@ticket_id, @product_name, @price, @tax, @amount);" + 
"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
// Instantiate SqlCommand object with above query.
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ticket_id", ticket_id);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", pro2.ProductName);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@price", tPrice);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@tax", tax);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@amount", fixedAmountStr);
```

Just be warned that if you pass in a string, it will have to perform the conversion on the DB side, which can fail if it can't convert it. Better thing to do would be to get the strongly typed values (in other words, parse the amounts to make sure they're valid) and then pass those values into the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use string.format to create queries. Use a parameterized query instead.

For SQL Server:

```
var aDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
aDbCommand.CommandText = "insert into myTable(column1,columns2) values (@param1, @param2)";
aDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter{Name="@param1", SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Decimal, Value = aValue});
aDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter{Name="@param2", SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Decimal, Value = aValue});
aDbCommand.Execute();
```

Comment: Can u give an example of it pls?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tickets (ticket_id, product_name, price, tax, amount) VALUES (@ticket_id, @product_name, @price, @tax, @amount)`, and then on your SQL command object, you do `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ticket_id", ticket_id); sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", pro2.ProductName); ...` for all your parameters.